# Trying to print JSON data on success into a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to log out each object in the array I receive from the following get request and output it onto a HTML page, in list elements.

The following returns a array of grocery items: `{ id: 1 text: "Doritos" }`

I did this previously in PHP, but this is much different than before. Any tips to help me try something new and learn would be greatly appreciated!

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'www.classified.com',
    type: 'get',
    data: {
    },
    headers: {
       "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.info(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Is this a cross-domain request? If so you may be blocked from doing this in JS by the Same Origin Policy

Comment: Im not sure what your question is....?

Comment: Its grabbing a JSON file from an API. The console.info logs the items. I just need to create a loop to log each item onto a list in HTML.

Comment: Look through jQuery documentation about working with DOM. or just use `innerHTML` property of container.

Comment: So instead of console.info(data) I want to loop through the items and print the onto the page as html.

Comment: Thanks I have but I'm seeing if anyone wants to help, appreciate that though. I'm totally new to jQuery.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you are saying it will return array, so JSON will be like

```
success: function (data) {
   // if data is an Array like [...] 
    jQuery.each(data, function(i, val) {
      console.log(val); // prints { id: 1 text: "Doritos" }
       // header is Div containing ul
      $("#header ul").append('<li>'+val.text+'</li>');

    });

 }
```

Comment: What I want is to get it to add to the page as html <li>Doritos</li> etc. Thank you for the kind response.

Comment: Do not know why this got down voted. I can understand how I got downvoted, thats how it goes when your dumb around here. Thanks for the working solution man.